# Laravel eager loading result

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, laravel-3

I'm having trouble with eager loading in laravel

I have these models:

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

    public function translations() {
        return $this->has_many('Pagestl', 'page_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Pagestl extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'pages_tl';

    public function page() {
        return $this->belongs_to('Page', 'id');
    }
}
```

I want a specific page with its translation data of a specific language.
I retrieve the data like this:

```
$page_data = Page::with(array('translations' => function($query) {
    $query->where('lang_id', '=', 'nl')->first();
}))->find($id);
```

De result is ok-ish. I get all the page data and the translation of 1 language, dutch (nl). But in order to get a field from the language data I have to this:

```
$page_data->translations[0]->attributes['content_or_whatever'];
```

..which i find ugly. I feel i should only have to do something like:

```
$page_data->translations->content;
```

..but that gives me an error (Trying to get property of non-object).

Am I missing something or is this just the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find it necessary to do eager-loading here.

Both ways of doing it will result in 2 queries: select the Page with the given id and then find its first translation.

So, I would do:

```
$page = Page::find($id);
```

and then

```
$page_data = Pagestl::where_page_id_and_lang_id($page->id, 'nl')->first();
```

Then, assuming the content field exists in **pages_tl** table, we'll get it by doing:

```
echo $page_data->content;
```

Finally, your code looks alright; you don't have to have the second parameter when defining the relationships unless they are different from what Laravel expects.

I'll let you find where the problem is with your code (I couldn't figure out from the information given - could be something to do with strings.php)

Comment: I agree with your answer. Maybe it's the example because when you make something multilingual, you don't need all the languages, just the users language or the current one or whatever. And maybe then the "with" method is not suitable (yet..). The code gives me the error because I must loop through the relations data, I think because of the "has_many"-relation. (I'm fairly new to Laravel, so I might be a bit off about this.) Anyway, thanks for your help!